# Organize methods by return type or argument?

Tags: java, oop

I'm having a bit of a hard time articulating this problem. With different types, what considerations are there for how to organize methods that traverse the relationships to convert to a different type?

While being forgiving about the precise modelling, for example, imagine there are 3 classes all with many-to-many relationships between one another: `Car`, `Garage` and `ParkingPass`.

- A car can have multiple parking passes
- Parking passes allow cars to park in garages
- The same pass can be used for multiple garages
- The same pass can be used by multiple cars

I'll use pseudo-Java syntax, but I don't think this is language specific (or even OOP specific for that matter, although likely more relevant there). If someone wants to find out what garages a car can park in, the following methods seem equivalently valid:

Asking the `Car` object for its garages:

```
Car {
   Collection<Garage> getGarages();
}
```

Asking the `Garage` object for garages given a car:

```
Garage {
   Collection<Garage> for(Car);
}
```

Either way, the object will need to move through the `ParkingPass` class to resolve the relationship mapping, so there's no direct conversion between one object and another.

Looking at examples like Java's [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) (it takes an argument with roughly the same type as the class, and produces a different class), it would seem justifiable to do the `Car.getGarages()` method. Alternatively, looking at Guava's [ImmutableList.of](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#of-E-E-), this takes an argument with a "different" type and returns a value with the same type as the class.

Are there best practices guiding how to decide where to put a method? Possible solutions might include:

1. Put the method in the class that matches the method's return type. This would mean classes "know" how to turn other objects into themselves.
2. Put the method in the class that matches the method's arguments. This would mean classes "know" how to turn itself into other objects.
3. Introduce a utility class that consumes one object, does some domain specific manipulation, and returns another

A common failing for all of these methods is the permutation problem - if your classes form a highly connected graph whichever solution is chosen is going to grow large.

Comment: Stop thinking about relationships and start thinking about behaviors. What are the real business use cases here and business constraints? That's how you determine what behaviors goes where and what abstractions are required.

Answer (score 1):

It's natural - from an OO standpoint - to ask a `Car` what garages it can park in. OTOH, it is *not* very natural to ask **a** `Garage` about that, because it requires the `Garage` instance being inquired to have knowledge about other garages.

Comment: To paraphrase, it makes more sense for an instance of a car to transitively know about garages than the garage class knowing about all the garages that exist? Can you think of any reasons for that to make sense? Does the equation change if it were a static method - `Car.getGarages(car)`? Not saying that's a great use of a static method, just trying to understand the reasons for putting it one place or another.

Comment: A car knows about all the garages it can park in, but a garage may not know about other garages - that makes perfect sense to me. Of course, I've been assuming that we are discussing this from a very abstract domain-driven design perspective. In the real world, for other reasons, it may not be practical to have it either way. Instead typically you would have some sort of service interface that provides that kind of relationship data.

Answer (score 1):

Asking the `Car` is the better solution here, but it depends on the semantics, how you would actually think about a model. You could also introduce both methods, and one method just asking the other method for the actual value. So the question is which method is the actual source of information.

For this particular case, why wouldn't you Model `ParkingPass` as a class, that would actually serve the information that itself does contain.

```
class ParkingPass {
    Collection<Garage> for(Car);
}
```

That does seem the correct thing to do here for me.

Comment: Agreed that the semantics matter - sometimes it's obvious, many times it's less so. Introducing both methods seems like a lot of overhead - when you author the methods, presumably you're only going to be using one of them so the question becomes "which one should you use?". I like the idea of putting it on the "mapping" object though, that seems like it'd be more consistent overall.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the question of how to organize methods can be answered in terms of "by return type", "by arguments" etc. Rather, I think that where a method belongs (and how to organize code in general) always depends on the model that is to be represented by the code, so the question one should ask oneself is: *How could the code best represent the model I am trying to implement?*. Seeing as you asked this question, this is probably your aim anyway, so I assume we already agree on this. But let me elaborate.

Let's take your example with the cars and the garages. So we want to find out what garages a car can park in. Who decides whether a car can park in a garage? I would say that, ultimately, it is the garage's decision whether it allows to accomodate a car or not, so it might make sense to put a method in the Garage class that determines whether a car is allowed to park in that garage. On what conditions this depends, may it be the parking pass, the car's license plate, its color or whatever, is the sole concern of the garage.

But now we're in possession of a parking pass that might affect whether we are granted access to a garage. Does this mean the parking pass can decide as well whether we are allowed to park our car in a garage and that the validation method we put in the garage class might as well go into the parking pass class? No, the parking pass can only *claim* that a car is permitted to park in a garage, but this claim can only be valid with the garage's consent, so the validation method in the garage class belongs there alright.

Of course, it would still be useful to query the parking pass about its terms, and implementing this doesn't contradict putting the validation method in the garage class, since the two constructs represent something different, we just have to be aware of it. So how do we implement the parking pass' terms? Again, this depends on the model of the parking pass. Does the parking pass grant access to a defined, finite set of garages? Then the natural solution would be for the pass to contain a `Collection` of garages (for example, a `Set`). But maybe the the parking pass grants access to garages based on a certain property of the garage, for example, its location, or the company it is owned by. Then a `Collection` would not represent the terms of this parking pass. Even if you were able to collect all garages to which the terms of the parking pass apply (let's say, all garages within a certain location, which can only be a finite set), a `Collection` would not represent the terms of the parking pass, which will be relevant as soon as new garages are built or garages are closed down etc. So in this case, a better way to represent the terms of a parking pass would simply be a `Predicate<Garage>`. True, this does not allow us to iterate over all garages this car might possibly be allowed to park in (remember, ultimately it's the garage that decides, hence the word "possibly"), but this is not a shortcoming of the code, it's inherent to the model we represent with the code.

I assume the parking garage model was just a simplified example and the problems you had in mind when asking this question are more complex, but then, I don't think the question you asked can be answered in general, so I tried to answer it for the parking garage model.

Comment: You're correct that this is a simplified example - the actual resource model is overly specific and niche-y. I agree that a blanket rule like "look at the return type" doesn't make sense. I was definitely looking for the general case "what considerations go into this decision?". In particular, it seems like this is very difficult to stay consistent with as understanding of the resource model evolves.